# RecyclerView doesn't show anything and no show errors

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-adapter

I'm trying construct a activity without a fragment and it doesn't works and no show any error. In the Logcat, just the SemestreAdapter construct is instantiated. No exception is called.

MY Code:

`Activity` Class:

```
package passei.whereit.com.passei;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import passei.whereit.com.passei.Adapters.SemestreAdapter;
import passei.whereit.com.passei.Classes.Semestre;

public class Semestres_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView semestreRV;
    private SemestreAdapter semestreRA;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_semestres);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Semestres");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorIcons));
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        semestreRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        semestreRV.setHasFixedSize(true);

        semestreRA = new SemestreAdapter(this,setSemestreList());

        semestreRV.setAdapter(semestreRA);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        semestreRV.setLayoutManager(llm);
    }

    public ArrayList<Semestre> setSemestreList(){
        ArrayList<Semestre> list = new ArrayList<>();

        int[] s = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int[] m = new int[]{3,4,2,3,7,5};
        float[] n = new float[]{9.7f,3.4f,5.6f,7.6f,4.3f,6.7f};
        int[] f = new int[]{3,4,2,3,7,5};

        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
            Semestre semestre = new Semestre(s[i],m[i], n[i], f[i]);
            list.add(semestre);
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

**Adapter**:

```
package passei.whereit.com.passei.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.TextDrawable;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import passei.whereit.com.passei.Classes.Semestre;
import passei.whereit.com.passei.R;
import passei.whereit.com.passei.ViewHolders.SemestreViewHolder;

/**
 * Created by Leaandro Araujo on 04/03/2016.
 */
public class SemestreAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SemestreViewHolder>  {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Semestre> semestres;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;


    public SemestreAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Semestre> list){
        this.context = context;
        this.semestres = list;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Log.i("LOG", "SemestreAdapter()");
    }

    @Override
    public SemestreViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        Log.i("LOG", "onCreateViewHolder()");
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_semestre,parent,false);
        SemestreViewHolder viewHolder = new SemestreViewHolder(context,view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SemestreViewHolder viewHolder, int position){
        Semestre semestre = semestres.get(position);
        Log.i("LOG", "onBindViewHolder()");
        TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder().buildRound(semestre.toString(), Color.LTGRAY);
        viewHolder.ivSemestre.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        viewHolder.tvMaterias.setText(semestre.getMaterias());
        viewHolder.tvNotas.setText(String.valueOf(semestre.getNota()));
        viewHolder.tvFaltas.setText(semestre.getFaltas());
    }

    public int getItemCount(){
    return semestres.size();
    }
}
```

**ViewHolder**

```
package passei.whereit.com.passei.ViewHolders;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import passei.whereit.com.passei.R;

/**
 * Created by Leaandro Araujo on 12/03/2016.
 */
public class SemestreViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private Context context;
    public ImageView ivSemestre;
    public TextView tvMaterias, tvNotas, tvFaltas;

    public SemestreViewHolder(Context context, View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        Log.i("LOG", "SemestreViewHolder()");
        this.context = context;
        ivSemestre = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.semestre_number);
        tvMaterias = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.semestre_materias);
        tvNotas = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.semestre_notas);
        tvFaltas = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.semestre_faltas);

    }
}
```

**XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/colorIcons"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <include layout="@layout/app_bar" android:id="@+id/toolbar" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**RecyclerView Item XML Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/semestre_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"

    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/semestre_materias"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/semestre_notas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/semestre_faltas"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat print

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRJgm.png)

Comment: Can you post the `LOG`?

Comment: ´ 03-13 20:35:48.434 30166-30166/passei.whereit.com.passei D/PhoneWindowEx: [PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xfff5f5f5
03-13 20:35:48.434 30166-30166/passei.whereit.com.passei I/PhoneWindow: [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x fff5f5f5
03-13 20:35:48.469 30166-30166/passei.whereit.com.passei I/LOG: SemestreAdapter()
03-13 20:35:48.470 30166-30166/passei.whereit.com.passei I/Activity: Activity.onPostResume() called´

Comment: @LeandroAraujo Post it on your question the full logcat please.

Comment: 03-13 20:49:14.881 15415-15670/passei.whereit.com.passei D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000
03-13 20:49:14.938 15415-15415/passei.whereit.com.passei I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@e22be92 time:386415625
03-13 20:49:14.940 15415-15415/passei.whereit.com.passei D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false
03-13 20:49:14.944 15415-15415/passei.whereit.com.passei D/BubblePopupHelper: isShowingBubblePopup : false

Comment: link in the end of question

Comment: Semestres Array does have something on it? can you log the array?

Comment: how can I do it  ?

Comment: give `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView` a exactly height(like 400dp) and a conspicuous background(like #f00), to see if content shows. If it works,  it may be the problem in LinearLayoutManager.

Comment: the log of array shows: 03-14 19:46:54.134 7860-7860/passei.whereit.com.passei D/lista: [passei.whereit.com.passei.Classes.Semestre@1bfc2806, passei.whereit.com.passei.Classes.Semestre@39330ec7, passei.whereit.com.passei.Classes.Semestre@1e281cf4, passei.whereit.com.passei.Classes.Semestre@289edc1d, passei.whereit.com.passei.Classes.Semestre@e22be92, passei.whereit.com.passei.Classes.Semestre@11c7d063]

Comment: when I change the recyclerview it's cause an exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="#F00"
            />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it. I convert the items to String when I set text..

```
public void onBindViewHolder(SemestreViewHolder viewHolder, int position){
    Semestre semestre = semestres.get(position);
    Log.i("LOG", "onBindViewHolder()");
    TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder().buildRound(semestre.toString(), Color.LTGRAY);
    viewHolder.ivSemestre.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    viewHolder.tvMaterias.setText(String.valueOf(semestre.getMaterias()));
    viewHolder.tvNotas.setText(String.valueOf(semestre.getNota()));
    viewHolder.tvFaltas.setText(String.valueOf(semestre.getFaltas()));
}
```